# Auto-increment a number when DatabaseGenerated.Identity has already been used with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, identity, optimistic-locking

We have a situation where we are using Guids for our table keys.  Technically we selected GUIDs for their low chance of collision, and this application will some day be distributed, with a nightly data-sync between locations (hence, the need for the low collision chance ID)

However, the business wants a human readable number that can be used on-screen, printed repots, labels, and for use in conversation.  For that we're using a 5-digit number, starting with 10000.  These numbers can be duplicated across locations (Location A will have a Request 10000, Location B will too).

Our model looks something like this:

```
Public Class Request
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public int Number { get; set; }
}
```

Then in our save method, we're currently doing something like this:

```
newRequestNumber = (_dbContext.Requests.Max(r => r.RequestNumber)) + 1;

request.Number = newRequestNumber

_dbContext.Requests.Add(request);

_dbContext.SaveChanges()
```

Obviously this is very Naive, and we are now running into issues where that number is duplicated.

As far as I can tell, we can't annotate the Number property with DatabaseGeneratedOptions.Idnetity since it has already been used once.  I also can't find anything I could set using the Fluent API to mark this field as an auto-generated number.

My initial thought was to switch to some sort of optimistic locking strategy.  We would add a unique constraint to the request number, and then try to save it in a try/catch.  if it doesn't save, grab the number again, rinse and repeat.  The problem with this is that if the request fails to save for some other reason other than the unique number constraint, we'll be stuck in a loop.

I feel like I'm missing a fairly obvious solution here, any ideas?

Comment: Is it really desired to allow the IDs to be duplicated in different locations?  Can you eliminate that requirement?

Comment: What about setting up a REST service and all the locations can get their requests from the web service which will increment a counter after each request. That way you have one single entity issuing the request numbers and you won't have any collisions.

Comment: why not create a table that's single purpose is to create a new number?  you could have a row dedicated to a different purpose.

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by "human readable"? 10,000 may be human readable, but if you increment long enough you'll probably get to a point where nobody will want to read the number.

Comment: @DavidTansey The numbers being duplicated is a business requirement that we can't get around.  It was one of the first issues we brought up.  These locations act as independent entities, and rely on these numbers for purposes that software could solve, but they don't want (IE:  we had a Request number of 10020 yesterday, and today we have a request number of 100040, so we have had 20 new requests... not a fan of this but it's baby steps for these business users)

Comment: @GregoryHouseMD Unfortunately some of our locations have such unreliable internet connections that this wouldn't work.  Even if they had a connection that had 100% up time, the latency is brutal.

Comment: @Shoe That's an excellent point, but isn't a real concern for this particular application.  Each request that is submitted could take days to weeks to complete, so there is a bottleneck built into the process that's outside of the software system.  Additionally, we use those numbers as barcodes as well.  We initially tried to bypass this number altogether, but some of their labels are so small that they are un-scannable with their barcode scanners when use use a GUID for the label.

Comment: @TMcKeown I'm leaning towards this solution.  A simple table with an int set as database generated.  Not ideal, but workable.

Comment: cool, I will add as an answer =)

Comment: So does it have to be unique across locations or not? If it takes a while to process things and you are restricted to 5 digits. Isn't there potential for duplicate ids?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're not just using `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]` on the `Number` field?  You can leave it as an identity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a table with a single column to hold the integer key and another column for a name.  You could increment as needed, you could add more rows to represent different types of surrogate keys.

I wouldn't use an identity because that would require you inserting many many rows...  just update the column for the given row.

Comment: Accepted this as the answer because we're using SQL Server 2008, and this is actually one of Microsoft's recommendations to "Simulate Sequence Objects" - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlcat/archive/2006/04/10/sql-server-sequence-number.aspx

If we were using SQL Server 2012 or newer, we could use the CREATE SEQUENCE method - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx